# Reversible probability for a Markov Chain.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Considering the price of a share $X_n$ that evolves every $n$ day that increases of one euro with probability $0<p<1$ or decreases of one euro of probability $q=1-p$.

Assume that $X_0=10$ and $p<q$

> I already proved that $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ it's a homogeneous Markov Chain with transition matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}
>     q    & p & 0 &0& \dots &0& 0 \\
>     q    & 0 & p &0& \dots &0& 0 \\
>     0    & q & 0 &p& \dots &0& 0 \\
>      \\
>    0       & 0 & 0& \dots&q &0 &p
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

*The next question* is to show that $(X_n)$ admits a probability reversible $\pi$. $\pi$ is reversible if and only if $$\forall x,y\in [0,N]: \pi(x)P(x,y)=\pi(y)P(y,x).$$

So here it's equivalent to $\pi(x)P(x,x+1)=\pi(x+1)P(x+1,x)$ which can be written as $$p\pi(x)=(1-p)\pi(x+1).$$

I am not sure how can I continue.

Comment: Well, $\pi(x)=(p/q)\pi(x-1)=(p/q)^2\pi(x-2)=\cdots=(p/q)^x\pi(0)$ for every $x$ hence...

Comment: @Did I got that too, but what I need to do after that? Does it prove that $(X_n)$ admits a reversible probability?

Comment: Do you know any probability measure $\pi$ such that $\pi(x)=(p/q)^x\pi(0)$ for every $x$? (Sidenote: if indeed you had "got(ten) that too", you should have mentioned it in the question.)

Comment: @Did No, and this 'answer' your sidenote (de proche en proche..) : I was not satisfied with something $\pi(x)=$ because I don't know the value of $\pi(0)$ *and* I didn't know what doing next with that. Obviously, I missed something in my course ( in the light of math1000's answer ).

Comment: I disagree with your approach to the site and you definitely should have included what you had done into your question, however inconclusive these tries might have been.

Comment: @Did You are right, thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a birth-death Markov chain, so $$\nu_n = \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^n $$
is an invariant measure for $P$, that is, $\nu P=\nu$. To normalize $\nu$, we compute
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \nu_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^n = \frac{1-p}{1-2p}. $$
Set
$$\pi_n = \frac{\nu_n}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \nu_k} = \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^n\left(\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\right) = \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^n\left(1-\frac p{1-p}\right). $$
Then $\pi$ is a stationary distribution for $P$ as $\pi P = \pi$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n=1$. We have $\pi_0=1-\frac p{1-p}$ and $$\pi_{n+1} = \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^{n+1}\pi_0,$$
so $\pi$ satisfies the recurrence $$p\pi_n = (1-p)\pi_{n+1}, $$ as desired.

If we let $P^*_{ij} = \frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}P_{ji}$, then $P^*$ is the time reversal of $P$ with respect to $\pi$, having transition probabilities
$$
P^*_{ij} = \begin{cases}
p, & i=j=0\\
p, & j=i-1\\
1-p, & j=i+1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: After that do you know how can I compute the expected value of $(X_n)_n$? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming by that you mean $\mathbb E[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n]$? In that case because $P$ is aperiodic we have $\mathbb P(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=j)=\pi_j$ and so $$\mathbb E\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n\right] = \mathbb E[\pi] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\pi_n. $$

Comment: hm you are right, surely a typo in my exercise... Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a positive value for $\pi(0)$, equal to $\pi_0$. Then you have the recurrence relation

$$\pi(x+1)=\frac{p}{1-p} \pi(x),\pi(0)=\pi_0.$$

This recurrence can be solved explicitly: you get $\pi(x)=\left ( \frac{p}{1-p} \right )^x \pi_0$. Now normalize that.